# Service worker in an intranet

Tags: javascript, service-worker

A web application that runs in an intranet, needs to use the Service Worker API. According to the specs, this can only be done using HTTPS:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

To allow HTTPS access to our application from Ngnix, we have created self certificate using **openssl**. When we start the application the first time, we get the warning saying that the certificate cannot be trusted so you have to accept it. This is expected. After this, HTTPS is used, however we get an exception saying that:

```
An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.
```

After some search, it seems that since the certificate cannot be validated, we cannot use the Service Worker API. We are surprised by this. Does it mean that Service Worker API can **only be used with internet** or **having a certificate validator in the intranet**?

Before you guys start pointing it out, I know that there are similar posts asking the same question, however none of them gets a straight answer. Can we use Service Worker API with our constraints, intranet and no certificate validator: YES/NO.

Comment: Why not just trust the root CA that was used to generate the certificate in question?

Comment: How could I do this 'trust the roor CA' ?

Comment: Depends on the OS and browser, but you would want to set up something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate See MITM proxy for an example of an implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to use Service Workers in an intranet was given by Esqew. The steps are as follow.

Root CA:

- Create a root key
- Create and self sign a root certificate
- Install the root certificate in each of the devices you want to give 'secure' access to your web that uses Service Workers

For your web site

- Create a key for your web certificate
- Create the signing (.csr)
- Create the certificate using the signing and rootCA key. It is very important that the certificate contains the "alt_names", otherwise it for new browsers it is still not valid.
- Install the web certificate and key used to generate the web certificate in the web server.